# LISP program output

Tags: lisp, output

I am new to LISP and cant figure out What does the following LISP does?

```
(setq A '(RIGHT ARE YOU))
(print (reverse (list (first (rest A))(first (rest (rest A))) (first A) 'HOW)))
```

`setq` assigns lexical variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It prints:

```
(HOW RIGHT YOU ARE)
```

The first line assigns a list of the 3 elements to the symbol `A`. This is quoted to prevent evaluation of the `(RIGHT ARE YOU)` as a function called `RIGHT`. The second line does some needlessly verbose and complex logic to basically create a list consisting of four elements: the string `HOW` and the three elements from `A`.

Breaking down the second line:

- `(first (rest A))` - this returns the element `YOU` from `A`
- `(first (rest (rest A)))` - this returns the element `ARE` from `A`
- `(first A)` - this returns the element 'RIGHT' from `A`

This now leaves you with:

```
(print (reverse (list ARE YOU RIGHT 'HOW)))
```

Which LISP are you learning? Many LISP's have a notion of a REPL (read-eval-print loop) which lets you experiment with complex expressions and break them down into smaller chunks to understand the results of intermediate steps.

Comment: how did the position of YOU and ARE change?

Comment: i'm just starting with a book. complete newbie.

Comment: While your conclusion is correct the breakdown is still wrong. `(first (rest A))` is `'ARE` not `'YOU` and `(first (rest (rest A)))` is `'YOU` not `'ARE`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this transcript of a REPL session in Common Lisp will enlighten:

```
CL-USER> (setq a '(right are you))
(RIGHT ARE YOU)
CL-USER> (print (reverse (list (first (rest a)) (first (rest (rest a))) (first a) 'how)))

(HOW RIGHT YOU ARE) 
(HOW RIGHT YOU ARE)
CL-USER> a
(RIGHT ARE YOU)
CL-USER> (rest a)
(ARE YOU)
CL-USER> (cdr a)
(ARE YOU)
CL-USER> (first (rest a))
ARE
CL-USER> (cadr a)
ARE
CL-USER> (rest (rest a))
(YOU)
CL-USER> (cddr a)
(YOU)
CL-USER> (first (rest (rest a)))
YOU
CL-USER> (caddr a)
YOU
CL-USER> (first a)
RIGHT
CL-USER> (car a)
RIGHT
CL-USER> (values (first (rest a)) (first (rest (rest a))) (first a) 'how)
ARE
YOU
RIGHT
HOW
CL-USER> (list (first (rest a)) (first (rest (rest a))) (first a) 'how)
(ARE YOU RIGHT HOW)
CL-USER> (list 'are 'you 'right 'how)
(ARE YOU RIGHT HOW)
CL-USER> (reverse '(are you right how))
(HOW RIGHT YOU ARE)
CL-USER> '(how right you are)
(HOW RIGHT YOU ARE)
CL-USER> (print '(how right you are))

(HOW RIGHT YOU ARE) 
(HOW RIGHT YOU ARE)
CL-USER>
```